# How to calculate monthly mortgage principal/interest with overpayment

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a Google Spreadsheet with monthly mortgage payments (including principal/interest details) with an option of adding additional overpayments during the course of the loan.

Here's what I've got:

```
`RATE` - Annual Interest Rate
`LOAN` - Amount borrowed
`MONTH` - A period of the loan
 Length is 30, so 360 months/periods
```

Premium is fixed: `=PMT(RATE/12,360, -LOAN)`

This is how I calculate principle of a given month: `=PPMT(RATE/12, MONTH, 360, -LOAN)`

Interest on a given month is just `=Premium - Principle`

Here's the hard part:

I would like to calculate premium details (principle and interest) on a given month, that would include prepayment of the loan. So for example, on every month I want to overpay by $300 to see how much faster will I pay off the loan. But, beside to know the current balance of the loan (per month), I would also like to know month-by-month my principle and interests paid.

Is there a formula to calculate that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don’t have an exact answer for you but this [Jeff Su Mortgage Calculator](https://youtu.be/Z4vz8aa_vxs) tutorial might help

Comment: Happy to help, Ish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*entirely based on **Jeff Su's** amazing [Mortgage Calculator Tutorial...](https://youtu.be/Z4vz8aa_vxs)*

**Make an Amortization Table:**
*Let's say for the example that you have loan inputs above and are starting this table with headers on `A8` and the 1st row of formulas at `A9`*

FIRST ROW AFTER HEADERS:

1. **Period:** in `A9` put `=SEQUENCE(360,1,1,1)` (*or instead of hardcoding `360` point it at a cell that multiplies the term length in years x 12*).
2. **Payment Due Date:** in `B9` put `Jan 1, 2001` (*easier to see what year of payments you're in at a glance*).
3. **Beginning Balance:** in `C9` put your initial Loan Amount.
4. **Monthly Payment:** in `D9` put `=-PMT(RATE/12,360,LOAN)`
5. **Interest:** in `E9` put `=C9*(RATE/12)`
6. **Principal:** in `F9` put `=D9-E9`
7. **Extra Payment:** in `G9` put `300` or whatever you want your extra payment to be.
8. **Ending Balance:** in `H9` put `=C9-(F9+G9)`

**SECOND ROW AFTER HEADERS**

1. `A10` no action needed, should autofill.
2. `B10` enter `=EDATE(B9,1)`, then drag all the way down.
3. `C10` enter `=H9`, then drag all the way down.
4. `D10` enter `=MIN($D$9,SUM(C10+E10))`, then drag all the way down.
5. `E10` drag `E9` all the way down (if `E9` references a cell with the interest rate be sure to lock that reference).
6. `F10` drag `F9` all the way down.
7. `G10` drag `G9` all the way down.
8. `H10` drag `H10` all the way down.

**That should do it!** A good sanity check is to make sure the final "Ending Balance" value comes to exactly 0. Also a good idea to add sums above the Monthly Payment, Interest, Principal, and Extra Payment columns to ensure they all add up (the Sum of all Principal + sum of all Extra Payments should combine to equal the LOAN value).

Keep in mind that there are often other costs that go into a monthly payment (such as property tax, home owner's insurance, etc) that get paid into escrow each month, so your monthly payments may be higher.

The [CFPB has a lot of great resources](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/owning-a-home/loan-estimate/) if you're interested **AND always consult a financial advisor before making a big decision—don't rely solely on this google formula advice, use at your own risk :)**